# Binding a UDP port - How long does the binding persist in a NAT environment?

Tags: udp, port, nat

As UDP is not connection-based, does the port that a UDP socket is bound to, remains bounded until the lifetime of the thread or process that bound the socket to the specific port?

Also, there is the NAT binding issue which is separate from the above issue. I presume that the period for which the NAT binding persists is based upon individual NAT implementations. However, typically, do NATs have a specific, (though not standardized time) that NAT bindings are expected to remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varies wildly between NATs.

As long as traffic is flowing in both directions, the port should remain open.  Otherwise, in the absence of traffic, the NAT could release port mapping after a minute.

In one application I've worked on, the client and server do a periodic ping between each other every 45 seconds just to keep the port mapping open.

Depending on your applicaiton design, be prepared to have reconnection logic as needed when the port goes dead.

Comment: And as for socket binding, that should remain bound to the port until the thread/process persists, right? I think it it is logical but because there is the concept of implicit binding I am asking this question.  Do you know of any open source NAT binding software focused exclusively on NATs? I know iptables, nftables and some others offer NAT as part of a much larger offering.

Comment: Default for Cisco routers is 5 minutes. This is generally configurable on the router as the "UDP Timeout"

Comment: @asinix The socket binding to the port persists until the socket is closed, however that happens.

Comment: That NAT likely doesn't know anything about the socket binding on the PC. So in theory, you could close the socket, and then re-open it on the same port. However, the Windows PC's software firewall also be monitoring port activity - if it sees the socket closed (or application exit), it might drop its firewall exception as well.

Comment: @selbie  Related question... when iptables-like tools/routers implement port-translation NAT, do they actually create two sockets,  and then read and write to forward traffic? If so, anyone can easily write basic NAT with a little socket programming. Or does iptables do something else more efficient based upon some other system calls?

Comment: sometimes NAT rules are dropped after as little as [15 seconds](https://youtu.be/BazWPeUGS8M?t=1740).  iptables is all in the kernel and it operates at the packet level.  the berkeley socket API are what user level programs generally deal with, while routers in the middle shouldn't know or care about this interface

Answer (score 3):

The socket will remain bound to the port as long as it is open.  When the socket is closed (which happens automatically on process exit, but may happen earlier if the process does an explicit close), the port is unbound as part of the close process.

As with any file descriptor, if it is shared between multiple processes (via fork or whatever), it is only actually closed when all processes close it -- if at least one process still has it open, it remains open.